# How would you reproduce a tagging system like the one StackOverflow uses?

Tags: sql, search, logic, tagging

I am trying to produce a tagging system for a recruitment agency model and love the way SO separates tags and searches for the remaining phrases.

How would you compare the tags in a table to the search query etc...

I have come up with the following but it has some hickups...

1. User enters search query
2. Full text SQL contains() search on tbl_tags
3. Returns 5 results
4. Check if each "exact tag phrase" exists in original query string.
5. If it does exist then add tagID to array.
6. Remove tag names from original search string...
7. Search in tbl_people for people with linked TagIDs and search text fields with remaining text.

Example search : French Project Managers with Oracle experience

Tags : [French] [Project Manager]s with [Oracle] experience

Remaining text : s with experience

Now the problem comes when I search for Project Managers it leaves me with a surplus "s"... and there are probably other bugs with this logic too that I cannot account for...

Any ideas on how to make the logic perfect?

Thanks in advance, I understand this might be a bit of an abstract question...

Comment: This question is probably more appropriate on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Hmm ok how do I move it?

Comment: Flag for moderation, select "other" and enter your request to move it.

Comment: @Péter Török - I disagree, it's about how to produce a tagging system *like* the one on SO, not simply asking for information on how it works in order to use it.

Comment: I think it's appropriate here as the poster wants to know the technical side of how to code the system.

Comment: I flagged it now :\ too late... I might get moved either way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a key ingredient of how StackOverflow does its search.  SO requires that the user delineate the tags in the search string by explicitly putting brackets around the tags.  The (probably simplified) logic would then be.

1. Extract marked tags using regex to detect contents inside brackets
2. Using list of most common tags, scan string for unmarked tags and extract them.
3. Remove tag meta characters
4. Perform full-text search, filtered by tags

Comment: @Chris - interesting, that doesn't show up in the "how-to".  A little experimenting with tags on the last page of tags shows that it doesn't work for all tags.  I suspect there is a "most used" or "most search" list that is used to scan for tags in the search string after step 1.  I'll update.

Comment: Thanks, I am wondering how it knows the difference between for instance... "web-developments" as a phrase and web-development as a tag..

Comment: @Chris - maybe pluralize the regex? Searching the string for "(^| )web development(s?)" would match.  You'd add that tag to your set of tags and extract the matched text.  Except they don't try that hard: searching for "web developments" doesn't actually match the tag in SO.

Comment: That might solve the problem, I will add in extra search variables with plural and non plural versions... :) If you update your answer above and it works Ill tick it off :)